# Java OutOfMemoryError creates dump file as set in jvm parameter, but log file is not created as desired

Tags: java, out-of-memory

Hello Experts, 
I'm currently trying to simulate an **OutOfMemoryError** in Java 1.7, and having  problem with JVM crash log files, which is what I intend to see and analyze.

- OS: Linux(CentOS) 5.3
- Java: Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15), HotSpot 64-bit Server VM

---

**What I've done || tried so far**

1) Generate a java class to simulate an **OutOfMemoryError**.

```
class CrashTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "test";
        String concatToken = "concat...concat...concat...concat...";

        while(true) {
            str = str.concat(concatToken);
            System.out.println(str.length());
        }

}
```

2) Compile: `javac CrashTest.java` → **CrashTest.class** is generated.

3) Run with options listed below:

```
java -Xms2M -Xmx4M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
     -XX:HeapDumpPath=${PATH_TO_DUMP} -XX:ErrorFile=${PATN_AND_FILENAME_FOR_ERRORLOG}
     CrashTest
```

here,  I specify heap dump path and log path(`-XX:ErrorFile`).

4) As desired, the program exits with **OutOfMemoryError**.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to ${PATH_TO_DUMP}/java_pid31696.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [3258958 bytes in 0.048 secs]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.String.concat(String.java:1975)
    at CrashTest.main(CrashTest.java:9)
```

This is what I've done so far. I get the heap dump file(*.hprof) as specified in JVM parameter, and it's working fine up to this point. 
The problem is with JVM crash log file(which is, as far as I know, generated in the same path as the path in which the class file is located by default). I can't find any log file in the path specified in `-XX:ErrorFile`. I've tried a few things to resolve this issue:

1. Ran **CrashTest** without an `-XX:ErrorFile` option and searched the whole user directory for log file, but couldn't find any *.log file.
2. Checked for privileges for the directory specified for the error log, and it had no problem(permission for read, write, execute all granted).

Am I missing some important point? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think JVM only creates the log file when a fatal error occurs somewhere in the native code. The "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space " error is probably handled in the native code and not considered a fatal error, that's why it won't create any log file.

If you'd run out of swap space or physical memory (native memory), I think that would induce a "proper" fatal error, which would create the log file on the expected directory given in -XX:ErrorFile

Comment: @gybandi i was beginning to think that that could be the case. Thank you. I will investigate :)